# Как программно установить layout_marginTop?

Tags: java, android

Я вот, что придумал, мне нужно, чтоб `layout_marginTop` был ровно на половину экрана и тут вопрос. Если я установлю в XML файле половину "на мой взгляд" экрана, допустим `250dp`то на устройстве с другим разрешением это не будет половина. Вот, что я хочу сделать, я программно могу получить высоту экрана поделить ее на 2 и получившееся значение установить как `layout_marginTop` тогда это будет точно половина в не зависимости от разрешения экрана... Но нет такой функции `setMarginTop()`. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Вы вкорне изменили вопрос, на который вам уже был дан ответ. Так делать нельзя. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> public void setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

Устанавливает отступы в pixels. [setMargins](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что вы применяете метод `setMargins()` непосредственно к полученному объекту, который данный метод не имеет.

Класс `android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` имеет этот метод. Его наследуют:
`FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` и `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Попробуйте так:

```
//Получаете объект, который вы хотите изменить
AutoFitTextureView mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView)findViewById(R.id.texture);  

LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
param.setMargins(10,15,20,35);//left, top, right, bottom

mTextureView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

И если что, есть еще замечательное свойство `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`