# FlexboxLayout | Android

Tags: java, android, flexbox

Недавно узнал про FlexboxLayout. Добавил туда элементы (программно). Возникла проблема, у элементов нет отступов, хоть я их и прописывал. Что делать?

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margin = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)element.getLayoutParams();
```

Больше не работает.

```
int pos = 0;

        for(String genre : genres){
            TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
            text.setId(pos+1);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text.setLayoutParams(params);

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margin = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)text.getLayoutParams();

            margin.setMargins(0,0,10,0);

            text.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.genre_text_view, null));
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setText(genre);
            text.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorHeader, null));
            text.setTextSize(12);
            text.setPadding(6,3,6,3);

            pos++;

            genreLinear.addView(text);
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как программно установить layout\_marginTop?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505795/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-layout-margintop)

Comment: Сначала назначьте отступы и только потом передайте параметры представлению: `params.setMargins(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
text.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: Возможно вы просто не видите эти отступы, потому что они очень маленькие. setMargins — использует измерения в пикселях.